# Is "drive a road" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, verbs, transitivity

I read somewhere

> When **driving a 2 lane road** for a long period of time with very few places to pass other vehicles, a line of cars tends to develop behind the “slow” vehicle.

When using the verb "drive" transitively, can you say "drive the road"? Shouldn't it be "drive down that road"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously you can't *drive* a road of any kind.  You are correct and the sentence *means* "drive down a two-lane road" ... but then English doesn't always obey expectations.

In this case I would consider it an idiomatic expression, generally only used when talking about a *particular kind* of road.  For example:

> When **driving a multi-lane highway**, slower cars should keep to the outside.
>
> When **driving the open road** in your new Ford Mustang, take the long way home.

This pattern isn't limited to just driving, though.  There are many verbs that can be used:

> When **racing a circular track**, take advantage of the banked curves to keep your speed up.
>
> When **skiing a slope** that's above your usual skill level, be sure to watch out for unexpected hazards.

As with most idiomatic expressions, you have to learn from experience which sound natural and which don't.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you would drive down a road, on a road, or something similar.

After all, for someone to be "driving a road" (perhaps ushering the road across the prairie like a cowboy drives cattle) it would be quite an event.  The transitive verb "drive" doesn't make much sense with a road.